# Dead node in Pacemaker cluster: "Couldn't complete CIB registration"

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I have a situation where a two-node Pacemaker cluster does not work any more after an upgrade. Package versions are `pacemaker 1.1.16-1~bpo8+` and `corosync 2.4.2-3~bpo8+1` under Debian Jessie.

Pacemaker is still able to start on one node. `crm_node -l` then lists that node as online, the second one as lost.

Pacemaker can no longer start on the second node. The following log messages in `/var/log/corosync/logfile` seem pertinent:

```
cib: info: validate_with_relaxng: Creating RNG parser context
pacemakerd: error: pcmk_child_exit: The cib process (1234) exited: Key has expired (127)
pacemakerd: notice: pcmk_process_exit: Respawning failed child process: cib
...
cib: info: validate_with_relaxng: Creating RNG parser context
pacemakerd: error: pcmk_child_exit: The cib process (1235) exited: Key has expired (127)
pacemakerd: notice: pcmk_process_exit: Respawning failed child process: cib
...
crmd: warning: do_cib_control: Couldn't complete CIB registration 1 times... pause and retry
...
crmd: warning: do_cib_control: Couldn't complete CIB registration 16 times... pause and retry 
crmd: notice: crm_shutdown: Shutting down cluster resource manager | limit=1200000ms
pacemakerd: notice: pcmk_shutdown_worker: Shutdown complete
```

So it appears as if the second node attempts CIB registration and cancels the Pacemaker start after 16 failed attempts, and that the first node coniders the second as dead perhaps because it cannot register.

Who can one get out of a situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause turned out to be a too old version of package `libpe-rules2`, which provides `libpe-rules2.so`. Package `pacemaker` from `jessie-backports` requires only `>= 1.0.10` (perhaps a bug in the current package description), but the current version of `libpe-rules2` (also from `jessie-backports`) is 1.1.16.

The older version of the library made process `cib` fail because of undefined symbols in the dynamic library. This was revealed by starting `pacemakerd` (and in effect `cib`) with `strace -f`. Upgrading with `apt-get install libpe-rules2` resolved the situation.